# How to position spawned objects in diamond and grid (row x column) arrangements

Tags: unity

I am creating clones of my objects using the code below:

```
public List<Vector3> clonePositions;
public List<GameObject> cloneObjects;

for (int i = 0; i < clonePositions.Count; i++)
    {

        cloneObjects.Add(Instantiate(clonedObject,
        clonePositions[i], quaternion.identity));

    }
```

How can I create and position the cloned game objects in a grid/matrix (row x column) arrangement  (with equal spacing between and at equal spacing at the sides)? as seen below:

[image]

and also in a diamond shape arrangement as below:

[image]

I would like to keep the clones centered around the original game object.

Answer (score 1):

You should use nested for loops:

```
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x * size, y * size, 0);
        cloneObjects.Add(Instantiate(clonedObject, pos, quaternion.identity));
    }
}
```

Where width is the grid width, height is the grid height and size is the distance between two points. The diagonal case can be achieved with a small change:

```
Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, -45);
for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        Vector3 pos = new Vector3(x * size, y * size, 0);
        Vector3 rotated = rotation * pos;
        cloneObjects.Add(Instantiate(clonedObject, rotated, quaternion.identity));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I would like to keep the clones entered around the original game object. I just updated the post.